# Drawing a conclusion of shorter distance

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis

In a proof of mine,

I draw the conclusion that if $a \leq b$ and $L > b$ then $|a - L| > |a - b|$.

Why is this valid? I'm trying to come up with a proof on first principles.

I know:

$ L > b \implies L - a > b - a$ and also that $|a - L| = |L - a| \geq L - a > b - a$

So $|a - L| > b - a$, but $|a - b| = |b - a| \geq b - a$ and this is where I get stuck.

The intuition is simple: if L is bigger than b, and a is always less than or equal to b, then the distance to L will always be greater than the distance to b.

Comment: If $a \leq b$, then $|a-b|=b-a$. Since $L>b \geq A$, you have that $|a-L|=L-a$. Can you finish it from there?

Comment: So since $L > b$, we have $L - a > b - a$? Thanks a lot. So you broke down absolute value, found one case for each, then proceed to compare directly by what they are equal to.